# My calendar doesn't refresh when I first enter the screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

So basically, I'm trying to create a appointment booking app. I have this "bug" that every time I open the screen of my calendar it doesn't automatically refresh the available timeslots, even though I am calling the _fetchAvailableTimeSlots(_selectedDate); in both the initState and _onDaySelected (this is the function that's called on switching days in the calendar) functions. Here is the calendar page code:

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, unnecessary_null_comparison, avoid_single_cascade_in_expression_statements, curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures, non_constant_identifier_names, avoid_print, sized_box_for_whitespace, prefer_final_fields

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class BookMassage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookMassage({super.key});

  @override
  State<BookMassage> createState() => _BookMassageState();
}

class _BookMassageState extends State<BookMassage> {
  //include hive
  final myBox = Hive.box('UserInfo');
  // Declare necessary variables for saving the  available slots, timesslots and cached slots
  late DateTime _selectedDate;
  Map<DateTime, List<String>>? _availableTimeSlots;
  CollectionReference _timeSlotsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MassageBookedTimeSlots');
  late Map<DateTime, List<String>>? _cachedTimeSlots = {};
  //variable for today
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();

  // Initialize state when the widget is created
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Set the selected date to now and fetch the available time slots
    _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    _availableTimeSlots = {};
    _availableTimeSlots![_selectedDate] = generateAvailableTimeSlots();
    // Fetch the latest available time slots for the selected date
    setState(() {
      _selectedDate = _selectedDate;
    });
    _fetchAvailableTimeSlots(_selectedDate);
  }

  List<String> generateAvailableTimeSlots() {
    // Create a list of available time slots from 8:00 AM to 8:00 PM, 30 minutes apart
    List<String> timeSlots = [];
    for (int hour = 8; hour < 14.5; hour++) {
      for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute += 30) {
        timeSlots.add(
            '${hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}');
      }
    }
    return timeSlots;
  }

  Future<void> bookTimeSlot(String selectedTimeSlot) async {
    // Book a selected time slot if it's available
    if (_availableTimeSlots![_selectedDate]!.contains(selectedTimeSlot)) {
      setState(() {
        _availableTimeSlots![_selectedDate]!.remove(selectedTimeSlot);
      });
      // Update Firestore with the booking information and remove the booked time slot
      await _timeSlotsCollection
          .doc(_selectedDate.toLocal().toString())
          .update({
        //remove the booked timeslot from the array
        'timeSlots': FieldValue.arrayRemove([selectedTimeSlot]),
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAvailableTimeSlots(DateTime date) async {
    if (_cachedTimeSlots!.containsKey(date)) {
      // Use cached data if available
      setState(() {
        _availableTimeSlots![date] = _cachedTimeSlots![date]!;
      });
    } else {
      // Fetch data from Firestore if not in cache
      final snapshot =
          await _timeSlotsCollection.doc(date.toLocal().toString()).get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final timeSlots = List<String>.from(data['timeSlots']);
        setState(() {
          _availableTimeSlots![date] = timeSlots;
          // Cache the data
          _cachedTimeSlots![date] = timeSlots;
        });
      } else {
        // If no data is available, generate time slots and store in Firestore
        final generatedTimeSlots = generateAvailableTimeSlots();
        await _timeSlotsCollection.doc(date.toLocal().toString()).set({
          'timeSlots': generatedTimeSlots,
        });
        setState(() {
          _availableTimeSlots![date] = generatedTimeSlots;
          // Cache the data
          _cachedTimeSlots![date] = generatedTimeSlots;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // This method is called when a day is selected in the table calendar.
  // It updates the selected date and fetches available time slots for the selected date.
  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDate, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDate = selectedDate;
    });
    _fetchAvailableTimeSlots(_selectedDate);
  }

  //displaying message for errors
  void displayAreYouSureBooking(
      String timeSlot, Function()? onTap, Function()? onTapCancel) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                        "Are you sure you want to book a Massage at $timeSlot"),
                    SizedBox(height: 40),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        //CANCEL BUTTON
                        Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            height: 50,
                            child: TextButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    foregroundColor:
                                        MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
                                    textStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15))),
                                onPressed: onTapCancel,
                                child: Text("No, cancel"))),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),

                        //YES IM SURE BUTTON
                        Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            height: 50,
                            child: TextButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    foregroundColor:
                                        MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
                                    textStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15))),
                                onPressed: onTap,
                                child: Text("Yes I'm sure"))),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          TableCalendar(
            calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
            focusedDay: _selectedDate,
            firstDay: today,
            lastDay: DateTime(2024),
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
              return isSameDay(_selectedDate, day);
            },
            headerStyle:
                HeaderStyle(titleCentered: true, formatButtonVisible: false),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
              ),
              itemCount: _availableTimeSlots![_selectedDate]?.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final timeSlot = _availableTimeSlots![_selectedDate]![index];
                return Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 90,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                      //text button representing each timeslot
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          displayAreYouSureBooking(timeSlot, () {
                            bookTimeSlot(timeSlot);
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }, () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(timeSlot),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried a bunch of things, googling on how to refresh pages, but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Try calling _fetchAvailableTimeSlots under the setState(). In _onDaySelected() method you have called it outside the setstate().